# Flag based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

Being this my initial dataset:

```
x <- c("a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d")
y <- c("a","a","a","b","c","c", "d", "d")
z <- c(5,1,2,6,1,1,5,6)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I am trying to create a column in a dataframe to flag if there is another row in the dataset with the following condition:

- There is a row in the dataset with the same "x" and "y" columns. And at least 1 of the rows of the dataset, with that "x" and "y" has a "z" value >= 5

With the example provided, the output should be:

```
x y z  flag
1 a a 5  TRUE
2 a a 1  TRUE
3 b a 2 FALSE
4 b b 6 TRUE
5 c c 1 FALSE
6 c c 1 FALSE
7 d d 5  TRUE
8 d d 6  TRUE
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why is 2nd row (a -a -1) TRUE? And why is row 4 (b -b -6) FALSE? It seems that you need this? `(df$x == df$y) & df$z >= 5`

Comment: I think I did not explain myself correctly, sorry. The condition for "z" is not that the row itself is >= 5, but that exists a row with the same "x" and "y" that has a "z" >= 5. In this case, row 2 is TRUE as row 1 makes correct that characteristic.

Comment: Edited the problem statement!

Comment: x and y need to be same within a row or just between the row?

Comment: between the row, if 3rd row had a "z" value = 5, should be TRUE. I think I used a really bad example, very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `data.table` package for all my aggregations. With this package I would do the following:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
# by=.(x, y): grouping by x and y
# find all cases where
# 1. the maximum z value is >= 5
# 2. there are more than 1 entry for that (x, y) combo. .N is a data.table syntax for number of rows in that group
# := is a data.table syntax to assign back in to the original data.table
dt[, flag := max(z) >= 5 & .N > 1, by=.(x, y)]

# Does x need to equal y? If so use this 
dt[, flag := max(z) >= 5 & .N > 1 & x == y, by=.(x, y)]

# view the result
dt[]

# return back to df
df <- as.data.frame(dt)
df
```

Comment: given the last OP comment, as I understand it, you don't need the `x==y` condition

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
> within(df, flag <- x==y & z>=5)
  x y z  flag
1 a a 5  TRUE
2 a a 1 FALSE
3 b a 2 FALSE
4 b b 6  TRUE
5 c c 1 FALSE
6 c c 1 FALSE
7 d d 5  TRUE
8 d d 6  TRUE
```